# execute two different methods of ActiveRecords in one transactions

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, transactionscope

Is there any possible way to define a transaction for active record methods? I have Two activeRecords named as Answer and QuizMark which have tow method.I want say server to execute them as a trasaction. here is my code :

```
public function actionChangeAnswersStatus($formId, $userId) {
        if (isset($formId) && isset($userId)) {
            Answer::changeIgnoreStatus($formId, $userId);
            QuizMark::changeIgnoreStatus($formId, $userId);
            echo 'quizes';
        }
    }
```

is there any possible solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$connection = $this->connectDb();
$transaction = $connection->beginTransaction();

// You commands

$transaction->commit();

// Note: if an error occurs, call rollBack...

$transaction->rollBack();
```